# Algorithm for all subsets of Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, subset

I'm looking for algorithm which will create all subsets of array like if array is

```
A = [1, 4, 6]
```

algorithm will generate:

```
[1,4,6,[1,4], [1,6], [4, 6], [1, 4,6]]
```

Note : I'm looking for help with algorithm not some function.

Comment: Can you please mentioned what did you tried so far?

Comment: What about `[]` ?????

Comment: @VarunNarisetty I have tried yet is making all combination but missing some 
like if array is [1, 2, 3, 4]

it will miss subset [1, 3, 4], and make all other solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a backtracking based solution to formulate all the possible sub-sequence for the given array. Sharing an ideone link for the same: https://ideone.com/V0gCDX

```
all = []

def gen(A, idx = 0, cur = []):
    if idx >= len(A):
        if len(cur): all.append(cur)
        return

    gen(A, idx + 1, list(cur))
    incl = list(cur)
    incl.append(A[idx])
    gen(A, idx + 1, incl)

def solve(A):
    global all
    all = []
    gen(A)
    return all

print(solve([1, 4, 6]))
```